# How to upgrade a pip-installed module but not Django?

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm using pip to manage python modules in a virtualenv, currently with Django 1.8 website. I want to upgrade some of the modules but they start upgrading me to Django 1.9 (which I don't want to do quite yet).

I guess this is because of requirements in the modules' `setup.py` files. e.g., [django-treebeard specifies](https://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard/blob/master/setup.py):

```
install_requires=['Django>=1.7'],
```

And [django-recaptcha specifies](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/blob/develop/setup.py):

```
install_requires = [
    'django',
],
```

Is there (a) any way I can upgrade such modules but stop them upgrading Django, or (b) any way the module authors can specify Django versions without having pip automatically upgrade Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip has a `--no-deps` switch. You can use that.